# Skyrim special edition on PS5 "using PS4 disc" having follower bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm playing Skyrim special edition on the PlayStation 5 using the PlayStation 4 disc to play the PS5 upgrade edition.

After beating Dawnguard and going back to Dawnguard fort I decided I wanted to part ways with Serana, but for some reason when I tried to talk to her to get her to follow me again there is no dialogue option to come with me. The only option is just to craft arrows or something about her vampirism.

I have no idea how to fix this and I've looked up videos and they look like a serious pain just to get my follower fixed. Does anyone have any tips on how to fix this bug? If so please let me know because I am stuck.

Comment: *I've looked up videos and they look like a serious pain just to get my follower fixed* - Can you elaborate on that? Why didn't you try that beforehand?

Comment: I was in the middle of a quest and I had to go In there anyways when I was finished and I headed back to dawnguard Fort that's when I realized she was bugged and I was like oh crap I mean she's been following me for the whole dawnguard story which I was playing for like 12 hours in total so it never crossed my mind that she could be bugged I found out a little too late
Also why 12 hours it's because I've been exploring a lot and not doing the main story the whole time

Comment: Trying to find a way to fix it but for such a simple bug who knew it's such a hassle just to fix a simple problem that never once happened to me this is the first time I ever had this bug now I got to repeat 20 hours of work to fix it kind of ridiculous wish there was another way instead of spending 15 minutes going through the castle just to get Serana just to fix it it'd be great if they updated their game instead of resorting to that way